# Set default extension webpage name in Bootstudio

Tags: html, web, edit, utilities

I'm using BootstrapStudio for create some pages for my site.
I usually use **htm** as extension for web pages instead of **html**, so I wonder if there is anyway to change the defautl html extension in BootstrapStudio.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in Bootstrap Studio but you can write a script to run when you export your site to change all the file extensions.

Try taking a look at https://bootstrapstudio.io/tutorials/export-scripts

If you are running Bootstrap Studio on linux the script would look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$1"
for f in *.html; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.html}.htm"; done
```